# Minecraft Error Java runtime? Problematic Frame: ig75icd64.dll

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301]
[08:39:10] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: WizardIMP
[08:39:12] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[08:39:13] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[08:39:13] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[08:39:14] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[08:39:14] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[08:39:14] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[08:39:14] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[08:39:15] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[08:39:19] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to node265.minecraft.toomanynodes.com., 41690
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Welcome, WizardIMP to PvP-Dimensions Open Beta!
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] [mcMMO] Running version 1.5.05-SNAPSHOT-b136
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] [mcMMO] www.spigotmc.org/resources/mcmmo.2445/ - mcMMO Website
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] WizardIMP joined the game
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Welcome, [Donator]WizardIMP!
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Type /help for a list of commands.
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Type /list to see who else is online.
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Players online: 1 - World time: 9:03 AM
[08:39:21] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] You have no new mail.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffc1e3db7c, pid=8484, tid=6112
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x55db7c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid8484.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: can you edit in C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid8484.log?

Comment: A crash dump is very vague. Firstly: what were you doing/trying to do when this occurred. Secondly: what version of Minecraft/Java are you using. Thirdly: are you using any mods. The more information you provide, the easier we can come up with the solution to your problem

Answer (score -2):

This is an issue related to Intel graphics. Those cards consume so much freaking RAM.

TO FIX:

- Open Minecraft.
- At the lower left, select "Edit Profile"
- Edit "JVM Options" so -Xmx becomes -Xmx:3G (if you have 4GB of RAM, otherwise it can be more)

Comment: And install OptiFine from here: http://optifine.net/downloads

Comment: It can reduce lag and it supports HD resource packs

Comment: Saying to use mods isn't really accepted. And if that still doesn't work, then we can't help him at all due to a modded client.

Comment: @RikerW - recommending mods is fine. Asking for help when your 200+ mods (from various modpacks) don't play nice with each other? That's what we don't deal with.

Comment: @RoccoT-RoccoDeveloping It doesn't quite look like the JVM is out of memory, so your answer might not work

Answer (score -2):

If it's a server I just delete it and get it back, but if that doesn't work try waiting and check your internet connection or wifi.But if it's regular minecraft I don't know try going on minecraft forums and commenting or asking Notch.

Comment: Addressing the second part of your answer: Asking someone to find help elsewhere is not a valid answer. Also, asking Notch wouldn't quite help, considering Minecrafy has 10M+ players.